# Using Jacobi-Anger Expansion to prove Bessel function property

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, bessel-functions

The Jacobi-Anger expansion is represented as

$$ e^{ix \cos\theta} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} i^{n}J_{n}e^{in \theta} $$

With this known value, I'm attempting to show that

$$ \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} |J_{n}(x)|^{2}dx = 1 $$

I know that with the relation of $ J_{-n}(x) = (-1)^n J_{n}(x) $, we have

$$ e^{ix \cos\theta} = J_{0}(x) + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} i^{n}J_{n} \cos(n \theta) $$

I do not know how to go from here.

I know that having this expression of $e^{ix \cos\theta}$, I can acquire the integral form of the Bessel function of the first kind.

$$ J_n(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(x \sin\theta - n\theta)\ d\theta $$

Comment: What you are trying to show is not true. Take $n=3$ for example then $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |J_n(x)|^2{\rm d}x \simeq 0.14$. For $n=4$ we get $0.0196$.

Comment: http://www.hit.ac.il/staff/benzionS/Differential.Equations/Orthogonality_of_Bessel_functions.htm